# Dojo chart won't display after addSeries

Tags: javascript, web, charts, dojo

I am trying to create a chart in dojo. The issue is, as soon as I try and add any data to the chart, the chart renders blank (no errors).

Code:

```
var cPosition
require(["dojox/charting/Chart","dojox/charting/themes/Claro", "dojox/charting/plot2d/Grid", "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default", "dojox/charting/plot2d/MarkersOnly",], function(Chart, theme, Grid, Default, MarkersOnly){

    cPosition = new Chart("chartPosition");

    cPosition.setTheme(theme);
    cPosition.addAxis("x", { 
        min: -180, 
        max: 180,  
        majorTicks: true,
        majorTick: {length:180}, 
        minorTick:{length:5},
        majorTickStep:180,
        minorTickStep:20
    });
    cPosition.addAxis("y", { 
        min: -180, 
        max: 180, 
        vertical: true, 
        majorTicks: true,
        majorTick: {length:180}, 
        minorTick: {length:5},
        majorTickStep:180,
        minorTickStep:20
    });

    cPosition.addPlot("Grid", { type: Grid,
        hMajorLines: true,
        hMinorLines: true,
        vMajorLines: true,
        vMinorLines: true,
        majorHLine: { color: "black", width: 2 },
        majorVLine: { color: "black", width: 2 },
        minorHLine: { color: "grey", width: 1 },
        minorVLine: { color: "grey", width: 1 },
        enableCache: true });

    cPosition.addPlot("default", { type: MarkersOnly });
    //cPosition.addSeries("series_markers", [{x:10,y:10}]);

    cPosition.render();
});
```

If I uncomment the line:

```
cPosition.addSeries("series_markers", [{x:10,y:10}]);
```

The chart turns blank (absolutely nothing on it). If I comment the line, the grid displays correctly but, of course, no data.

What I am trying to accomplish is create an x,y grid that will display a marker that corresponds to the position of an object.

Comment: I tried your example and it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/vn22S/

Comment: Ended up using JSXGraph which worked well for me and provided additional features.